# Ubuntu 19.04 doesn't boot, updated from 18.04 LTS

Tags: updates

I updated my Lenovo IdeaPad 700 15ISK  from 18.04LTS to 19 and now every time I boot from gdm3 it loads, with my stickynotes application still viewable and then it goes back to the gray page with my name on it within a few seconds

EDIT: i switched to lightdm and I can log in and my background loads with my stickynotes application but 
"Started bpfilter" or something like that and it just goes back to the login screen